# container auto hide when clicked outside the container

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make my own custom UI for a video player. It will include a options toggle button which will open a options container. The options container should not close when the user clicks anything within the container and the options toggle should toggle correctly. How can I make the options container hide when the user clicks else where on the screen? Thanks

I will also be inserting a number of video players in a single document.

```js
var oc = document.querySelector(".options_container"),
  ot = document.querySelector(".options_toggle");

oc.style.visibility = "hidden";

ot.onclick = function() {
  if (oc.style.visibility == "hidden") oc.style.visibility = "visible";
  else oc.style.visibility = "hidden";
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 95%;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.container .options_container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 5px;
}
.container .bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .bar img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin: 7.5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="options_container"></div>
      <div class="bar">
        <img class="options_toggle" src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/61/61f0d7caaee233b43ea8c5359c038c41.png">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.options_toggle').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
         $(".options_container").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $(".options_container").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".options_container").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 95%;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.container .options_container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 5px;
    display:none;
}
.container .bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .bar img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin: 7.5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="options_container"></div>
      <div class="bar">
        <img class="options_toggle" src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/61/61f0d7caaee233b43ea8c5359c038c41.png">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register a function to listen on click event. If the user clicks anywhere on the screen which is not container then it will close all the containers. You can further modify the function to implement more complex validation.

```
function closeContainers() {
  // Get all the containers
  let containers = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

  // If the user hasn't clicked on the current container then remove the visibility

  containers.forEach(function (container) {
   if (container.classList.contains('visible')) {
      container.classList.remove('visible');
   }
  })
}

// Close the container if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.container')) {
    closeContainers();
  }
}
```